# What is this tube along the right side of a Blue Angel?

Tags: aircraft-design

I was at the Museum of Flight in Seattle, WA, yesterday, and came across a Blue Angel aircraft, pictured below.

[image: The Blue Angel jet as seen at the exhibit]

Along the right front of the plane, there is a small tube that is capped with a silver cap.

[image: The tube on the side of the jet]

I thought at first that this might be a refuelling point, but (A) I didn't see any real purpose to have mid-air refuelling on a Blue Angel, and (B) it doesn't seem like a great place to refuel (since it seems like it could easily obstruct the pilot's view).

*(I looked online at some images of Blue Angel aircraft and realized there are several makes. However, I didn't find this particular tube and cap on any of the other makes. [(example)](http://redboxpictures.com/commercial/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/seafair_blue_angels_seattle-web-portfolio.jpg) In fact, I don't even recall what make of Blue Angel this craft actually is.)*

What is this tube at the front of the jet, and what is it used for? Why does it only appear on some makes of the jet?

Comment: Isn't it an A-4F Skyhawk?

Comment: It is a refueling probe.  The A-4 was very small and the probe was fitted where it could fit.

Comment: You need to look at it the other way. It would be extra work to modify aircraft for display team, so it is equipped exactly like a standard combat one.

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, but also consider that for some of their ferrying flights it was more convenient to do in-flight refueling, plus it maintained the pilots proficiency rating for the procedure.

Comment: I haven't seen a Blue Angels performance, but the Thunderbirds make a point that their airplanes are a paint job and a weapons load away from being combat ready.  A refueling probe may not have a purpose on a demonstration aircraft, but it's part of the standard equipment.

Comment: @Mark -- besides, refueling gear might be handy if they ever have to take a long trip overseas :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The aircraft is the A4 Skyhawk and the probe is for air-to-air refueling.

[image: A-4 refueling from KC-10, Navy photo]

As you can see, it doesn't really impede the pilot's view which in any case, is concentrated on the refueller.

You can always spot a refuelling probe. For NATO aircraft, and most others, they always have the same tip and are the only appendages which look like this.

The Blue Angels used it since transits to various air shows exceeded the range and air-air refuelling is cheaper and more effective than landing, refuelling and taking off again.

Comment: Actually, USAF and USN fighters use different refueling hookups. Navy fighters use the extended refueling probe on the plane with a "hose and drogue" on the tanker, shown in your image. The refueling plane can be further away, but making and maintaining contact is pretty much 100% pilot. The USAF adopted a "flying boom" that connects to a port behind the cockpit; this approach gets the plane further below and underneath the tanker, where the refueling link is then easier to maintain, and the pilot merely has to hold still while the boom operator makes contact.

Comment: The KC-10 in your picture supports both refueling methods with separate systems; you can see the V-tail of the flying boom tucked up just behind the tail. The KC-135 uses the flying boom as its primary refueling method, but can support Navy fighters with a drogue adapter either attached to the boom or to outboard pylons.

Answer (score 16):

It's a refueling probe. Below is a picture of it in action:

[image]